# Trying to upload a file into google app engine using Blob

Tags: google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload the file into google app engine from where I would like to retrieve it and then perform conversion into a pdf file. I want to have a cloud access so I am deploying this project. But I dont the best way to go about it. Can anyone help please ? Or is there any solution to directly convert the file while being on the server ?

Comment: I am trying to convert a word file to PDF. So I'm trying to upload a .doc file...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any ways to convert a file directly on the server. But to store and retrieve, you might want to take a look into the [Google Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) (and the one [from Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/), if needed).

These might help as well ([Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) and [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted)).  From there you can easily save a file, then retrieve it. Once you retrieve it, do your conversion to pdf and voila!